# Command Prompt: run scripts in background (equivalent of Linux's &/bg)

Tags: windows, command-line

In Linux you can do this:

> $ php blah.php > some.log &

to run `blah.php` in the background. This is the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> then the `bg` command.

Is there an equivalent of either/both for the Windows Command Prompt?

Comment: I don't believe there is, but you can launch as many command prompts as you need.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm using > to log to a file, and I don't want to prompt to just sit out there. I may want to continue working on the same prompt window w/ the same directory.

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Windows 7 (64-bit)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Windows does have a similar functionality to Linux's `&`, to launch processes such that they don't take over your console. Instead of a command-line flag, though, it's a command prefix.

Simply run your command with `start` in front of it, as such:
`C:\> start myprog.exe`

It also works with commands, not just executables:
`C:\> start dir`

This will start a new console window and run the command inside it.

If you don't want to have a new console window come up when running the command, use the `/B` switch, like this:
`C:\> start /B myprog.exe`

There are several other options you can specify to configure how to run the command. You can figure them out by reading the help for `start` by using `start /?`.

Comment: Is there any way to list the background processes and then kill them?

Comment: @JellicleCat You can use `tasklist` to get a list of running processes and their IDs. `taskkill` can then be used to end processes.

Answer (score 3):

I see some users have suggested using `start` with the `/B` option. A problem with this approach is that does not work well with console applications. At least in my experience, the child process always terminates once `cmd` is closed.

However, the PowerShell command `Start-Process -WindowStyle hidden <path to executable>` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

This can run a file in the background from the command prompt or a batch file

```
@Echo off
Echo Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   >>%temp%\ghost.vbs
Echo WshShell.Run chr(34) ^& "MyFile" ^& Chr(34), 0 >>%temp%\ghost.vbs
Echo Set WshShell = Nothing                         >>%temp%\ghost.vbs
start %temp%\ghost.vbs
timeout /t 1 >nul
del %temp%\ghost.vbs
```

Now replace `MyFile` with the file you wish to run in the background.

Comment: (1) Can you explain how this works (just a little)? (2) Fundamentally, this uses the `start` command.  It creates an intermediate thing that runs the user’s command, and then uses the `start` command to start the intermediate thing. So it’s a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine). How is this any better than the other answer, which suggests using `start` directly? (3) The question shows I/O redirection (`> some.log`). How would the user do I/O redirection with this answer? Put it on the command line, or build it into the `WshShell.Run` line in the script?

Comment: Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I tried putting "ssh -N -f -l" into Windows Powershell / command prompt, and it does go into the background, but then you have to kill the window to get rid of it. I would like to have a powershell script that runs "ssh -N -f -l" to establish a port tunnel, but then I wouldn't be able to put any new lines in the script after the ssh line, it just hangs there and executes the remaining lines only if ssh fails. I wish there was a powershell equivalent of Linux's ampersand so I could go to the next line and perhaps run mstsc.exe .

Comment: An interesting tidbit but also not a generalized solution